# Pokemon tag problems (Gotta Tag 'Em All)

Tags: discussion, tags, questions, pokemon

I was looking at [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6065/where-can-i-train-my-pokemon-in-heartgold-soulsilver-after-kanto) and got worried, should I remove those two extra tags ([soul-silver](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soul-silver) [heart-gold](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heart-gold))? So I asked in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8369544#8369544) and got a good point from StrixVaria:

> Pokemon is all messed up. There's a tag for Pokemon-fourth-gen but
>   this question doesn't apply to all the 4th-gen games, just the 2nd gen
>   remakes that are on the 4th gen engine. If you look through Pokemon
>   questions in general you'll find a lot of tagging issues.

And I think he is right. Pokemon should have a proper resolution so we could "fix" the questions without worry. So:

How should we treat the tags in those questions?

Comment: by @LessPop_MoreFiz: *"@StrixVaria I swear, if you title it or in any other way make a "Gotta Tag 'Em All" joke, I will downvote it out of spite."*

Comment: @Michel If you put "Gotta Tag 'Em All" as part of this post's title, I will upvote this post to counter that downvote. =)

Comment: @galacticninja Done =)

Comment: I was thinking that a few days ago too. The current situation is a total mess.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

One obvious thing to point out is that *every* question tagged [heart-gold](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heart-gold) is *also* tagged [soul-silver](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soul-silver). There really isn't much in the way of questions about one and not the other, so those two should be combined into a single tag.

We should use [pokemon-heart-gold-soul-silver](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-heart-gold-soul-silver)<sup>[[1]](//meta.arqade.com/a/12510/28182) [[2]](//meta.arqade.com/q/12831/28182)</sup>, with individual game tags ([pokemon-heart-gold](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-heart-gold), [pokemon-soul-silver](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-soul-silver)) and the community abbreviation ([pokemon-hgss](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-hgss)) made synonyms.

The generation tags (e.g. [pokemon-fourth-generation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-fourth-generation)) are good for questions about a specific generation. For questions about a specific set of games within a generation, we should use a game-specific tag, similar to my suggestion above.

For questions about the whole series, use [pokemon-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-series).

---

Here's an example list of tags following these criteria:

### First Generation

- **Main Tag:** [pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green) <sup>[[3]](//meta.arqade.com/q/16843/28182)</sup>
  <sup>Synonyms: [pokemon-red](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-red), [pokemon-blue](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-blue), [pokemon-yellow](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-yellow), [pokemon-green](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-green), [pokemon-rby](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-rby), [pokemon-first-generation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-first-generation), [pokemon-1st-generation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-1st-generation)</sup>

### Second Generation

- **Main Tag:** [pokemon-gold-silver-crystal](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-gold-silver-crystal) <sup>[[3]](//meta.arqade.com/q/16843/28182)</sup>
  <sup>Synonyms: [pokemon-gold](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-gold), [pokemon-silver](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-silver), [pokemon-crystal](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-crystal), [pokemon-gsc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-gsc), [pokemon-second-generation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-second-generation), [pokemon-2nd-generation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-2nd-generation)</sup>

### Third Generation

- **Generation Tag:** [pokemon-third-generation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-third-generation)
  <sup>Synonyms: [pokemon-3rd-generation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-3rd-generation)</sup>
- **Game Tags**

  - [pokemon-ruby-sapphire-emerald](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-ruby-sapphire-emerald)
    <sup>Synonyms: [pokemon-ruby](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-ruby), [pokemon-sapphire](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-sapphire), [pokemon-emerald](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-emerald), [pokemon-rse](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-rse)</sup>
  - [pokemon-fire-red-leaf-green](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-fire-red-leaf-green)
    <sup>Synonyms: [pokemon-fire-red](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-fire-red), [pokemon-leaf-green](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-leaf-green), [pokemon-frlg](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-frlg)</sup>

### Fourth Generation

- **Generation Tag:** [pokemon-fourth-generation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-fourth-generation)
  <sup>Synonyms: [pokemon-4th-generation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-4th-generation)</sup>
- **Game Tags**

  - [pokemon-diamond-pearl-platinum](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-diamond-pearl-platinum)
    <sup>Synonyms: [pokemon-diamond](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-diamond), [pokemon-pearl](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-pearl), [pokemon-platinum](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-platinum), [pokemon-dpp](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-dpp)</sup>
  - [pokemon-heart-gold-soul-silver](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-heart-gold-soul-silver)
    <sup>Synonyms: [pokemon-heart-gold](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-heart-gold), [pokemon-soul-silver](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-soul-silver), [pokemon-hgss](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-hgss)</sup>

### Fifth Generation

- **Generation Tag:** [pokemon-fifth-generation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-fifth-generation)
  <sup>Synonyms: [pokemon-5th-generation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-5th-generation)</sup>
- **Game Tags**

  - [pokemon-black-white](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-black-white)
    <sup>Synonyms: [pokemon-black](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-black), [pokemon-white](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-white), [pokemon-bw](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-bw)</sup>
  - [pokemon-black-2-white-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-black-2-white-2)
    <sup>Synonyms: [pokemon-black-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-black-2), [pokemon-white-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-white-2), [pokemon-bw2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-bw2)</sup>

### Sixth Generation

- **Generation Tag:** [pokemon-sixth-generation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-sixth-generation)
  <sup>Synonyms: [pokemon-6th-generation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-6th-generation)</sup>
- **Game Tags**

  - [pokemon-x-y](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-x-y)
    <sup>Synonyms: [pokemon-x](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-x), [pokemon-y](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-y), [pokemon-xy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-xy)</sup>
  - [pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire)
    <sup>Synonyms: [pokemon-omega-ruby](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-omega-ruby), [pokemon-alpha-sapphire](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-alpha-sapphire), [pokemon-oras](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-oras)</sup>

### Seventh Generation

- **Generation Tag:** [pokemon-seventh-generation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-seventh-generation)
  <sup>Synonyms: [pokemon-7th-generation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-7th-generation)</sup>
- **Game Tags**

  - [pokemon-sun-moon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-sun-moon)
    <sup>Synonyms: [pokemon-sun](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-sun), [pokemon-moon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-moon), [pokemon-sm](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-sm)</sup>
  - [pokemon-ultra-sun-ultra-moon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-ultra-sun-ultra-moon)
    <sup>Synonyms: [pokemon-ultra-sun](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-ultra-sun), [pokemon-ultra-moon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-ultra-moon), [pokemon-usum](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-usum)</sup>

---

<sup>[1] - [Increase tag length limit to 32 or 35](//meta.arqade.com/a/12510/28182)

[2] - [Expanding Tag Names for Pokemon](//meta.arqade.com/q/12831/28182)

[3] - [Petition to slightly alter how we handle early Pokémon game tags (Gen 1 and Gen 2)](//meta.arqade.com/q/16843/28182)</sup>

Comment: Looks perfect to me.

Comment: Let's not forget to make tag wikis for these to ensure clarity about their usage too.

Comment: @InvaderSkoodge - I think, given the almost certainty that there will be other sixth-gen games, we should probably start with both sets of tags.  Mechanics questions can go under the gen tag right out of the gate.

Comment: @Shinrai I am tempted to agree. This will also prevent tagging nightmares when the second set of games in gen 6 comes out.

Answer (score 8):

I think we should add a [pokemon-bank](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-bank) tag. There are around 10 questions now that specifically ask something about the bank, and only the bank.

For example:

- [Can a new save withdraw from the pokemon bank?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/155016/can-a-new-save-withdraw-from-the-pokemon-bank)
- [Pokemon Bank Switching Gifts pokemiles or battle points](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/155013/pokemon-bank-switching-gifts-pokemiles-or-battle-points)
- [What gifts can I get from the Pokemon Bank?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/156032/what-gifts-can-i-get-from-the-pokemon-bank)
- [If you delete your Nintendo Network ID, what happens to the Pokemon Transferred using Pokemon Bank and Pokemon Transfer?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/167416/if-you-delete-your-nintendo-network-id-what-happens-to-the-pokemon-transferred)

Most of them are tagger [pokemon-xy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-xy) or [pokemon-oras](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-oras), but they really ask something about the bank. Surely, the XY and ORAS tag have something to do with it, because the bank and the games are closely related, but above questions are specific about the bank, not the games.

The Pokemon Bank, for users who don't know it, is a nifty tool made by Nintendo to quickly exchange Pokemon stored in the ingame computer of XY/ORAS. In this way, you can transfer large amount (as in, the whole Pokedex) in a few minutes. It is a paid application (5 dollar per year, iirc) available in the eShop.