# Tag synonym - [heart-gold] / [soul-silver] -> [pokemon-hgss]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms, pokemon

Earlier discussion: [Pokemon tag problems (Gotta Tag 'Em All)](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6957/pokemon-tag-problems-gotta-tag-em-all)
(This post is to ask for a higher-rep user to take an action on something from that discussion.)

I already retagged all of the existing questions, and moved all the useful information from the tag wiki, but I can't suggest tag synonyms (that requires 2.5k+).

Tasks:

- synonym [soul-silver](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soul-silver) -> [pokemon-hgss](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-hgss)
- synonym [heart-gold](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heart-gold) -> [pokemon-hgss](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-hgss)

Answer (score 2):

With Pokemon Sun/Moon's imminent release I thought it was high time someone actioned this (as well as the other synonyms proposed by that other meta), so [this is now done](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=newest&filter=all).

Comment: Comment if you find any that are missing