# Pokemon X and Y tag canonicalization

Tags: support, tags, pokemon

Pokemon X and Y just came out yesterday, and predictably we have gotten an influx of questions. Unfortunately, some are tagged [pokemon-sixth-gen](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-sixth-gen) and some are tagged [pokemon-xy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-xy). These tags are being used for the exact same set of games right now, so I think we should use only one of those tags for all of those questions. I suggest [pokemon-xy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-xy) because all of the questions right now are specifically about those games and we don't know which of the questions will apply to other sixth gen games.

Answer (score 4):

This addressed in this meta answer: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6958/26487

- [pokemon-sixth-gen](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-sixth-gen) (For questions about generation 6 mechanics in general.)
- [pokemon-xy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-xy) (For questions specifically about X/Y)

Synonyms: [pokemon-x](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-x) [pokemon-y](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-y)

Comment: And right now, the two ARE interchangable; they mean one and the same.  Which is what's leading to the confusion; they're both valid.

Comment: I know how the tags are *supposed* to be used. The problem is that right now, as Frank points out, the only sixth generation games are X and Y, so tagging some questions with one tag and some with the other only serves to create an arbitrary split in the questions about the new games.

Comment: I'm sure most of the gen-6 tagged questions will be valid across multiple games in the future, e.g. the 'what old Pokemon are fairies now' question, etc. It's preemptive, so we don't need to do loads of clean-up later.