# Expanding tag names for Pokémon

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request, pokemon

I would like to propose renaming the following tags in the Pokémon series:

- [pokemon-rse](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-rse) → [pokemon-ruby-sapphire-emerald](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-ruby-sapphire-emerald) (29)
- [pokemon-frlg](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-frlg) → [pokemon-firered-leafgreen](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-firered-leafgreen)* (25)
- [pokemon-dpp](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-dpp) → [pokemon-diamond-pearl-platinum](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-diamond-pearl-platinum) (29)
- [pokemon-hgss](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-hgss) → [pokemon-heartgold-soulsilver](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-heartgold-soulsilver)* (28)
- [pokemon-bw](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-bw) → [pokemon-black-white](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-black-white) (19)
- [pokemon-bw2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-bw2) → [pokemon-black-2-white-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-black-2-white-2) (23)
- [pokemon-xy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-xy) → [pokemon-x-y](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-x-y) (11)
- [pokemon-oras](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-oras) → [pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire) (33)
- [pokemon-sm](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-sm) → [pokemon-sun-moon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-sun-moon) (16)

These expanded tags would match the naming used for [pokemon-ultra-sun-ultra-moon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-ultra-sun-ultra-moon).

We can also rename some spinoff games:

- [pokemon-super-md](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-super-md) → [pokemon-super-mystery-dungeon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-super-mystery-dungeon) (29)
- [pokemon-explorers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-explorers) → [pokemon-mystery-dungeon-explorers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-mystery-dungeon-explorers) (33), [the full names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Mystery_Dungeon:_Explorers_of_Time_and_Explorers_of_Darkness) are too long

Unfortunately [pokemon-hgss-pokewalker](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-hgss-pokewalker) can't be converted to [pokemon-heartgold-soulsilver-pokewalker](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-heartgold-soulsilver-pokewalker) because that's 39 characters.

---

**Author's notes:**

- The official titles for *FireRed/LeafGreen* and *HeartGold/SoulSilver* do not have spaces. These could be tagged in one of two ways.

  - Follow official title: [pokemon-firered-leafgreen](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-firered-leafgreen), [pokemon-heartgold-soulsilver](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-heartgold-soulsilver)
  - Use spaces for readability: [pokemon-fire-red-leaf-green](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-fire-red-leaf-green), [pokemon-heart-gold-soul-silver](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-heart-gold-soul-silver)
- Arqade currently uses a [dual-tag system for Pokémon](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6958/181240)  to distinguish generation-wide and game-specific questions.

  - Example: [pokemon-fifth-gen](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-fifth-gen) vs [pokemon-bw](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-bw) & [pokemon-bw2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-bw2)

Comment: If HeartGold and SoulSilver don't use spaces, why should they be used in the tag? If the games are called Black 2 and White 2, why should the tag be Black White 2?

Comment: I was just wondering what the reasoning behind that was

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer The current synonyms for [tag:pokemon-frlg] are [tag:pokemon-fire-red] and [tag:pokemon-leaf-green]. I think the spaced-spellings are more readable, but wouldn’t mind the tag either way.

Comment: Unlike most of the other tag renames we've done thus far to expand tags that were truncated out of necessity to meet the 25 character tag limit, the abbreviated Pokemon tags actually use the common Pokemon community agreed-upon abbreviations, decided upon [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6958/28182). As I mentioned on the [35 char upgrade Meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12511/28182) I'd want to see a community discussion & majority consensus before we action these.

Comment: Also - I much prefer a dash between the words i.e. `fire-red` over `firered`. As our tag system doesn't allow for capitalisation it just looks like we typo'd a tag otherwise.

Comment: Agreed with the fire-red tag over firered, I'm also in favor of the rename overall. It's much more detailed and just looks better than abbreviations IMO

Comment: My personal preference is to match Wikipedia's titles, so I would prefer `firered` over `fire-red`, but would not stand in the way of having the latter be the parent if that's the consensus. Maybe create a tag synonym for the alternate spelling?

Comment: @Thunderforge - We could but I'm not sure it would be needed: Tag search ignores dashes entirely. Try searching for 'needforspeed' on the tags page, or in the 'Ask question' tag box.

Comment: @Robotnik Yup, you're absolutely right. No need then.

Comment: Yes please. We're not animals, we can type full game names. (No offense to animals, my dog tries really hard but he hasn't defeated me in a Pokemon battle yet).

Comment: After thinking it over, I’m starting to lean towards [tag:pokemon-firered-leafgreen] over [tag:pokemon-fire-red-leaf-green]. As of late, there’s been a greater focus on matching game’s official titles.

Comment: @Robotnik Have we reached enough of a consensus to have these renamed or do we need to have more discussion?

Comment: @Thunderforge it's more of a case of me needing the time to sit down and action all of these at once. I don't want to do a couple then leave the rest in a halfway state. The other mods and I are also in the middle of a discussion about the [minecraft] tag situation and that has taken the majority of my time this week :)

Comment: @Robotnik Glad to hear that it's being discussed! We appreciate your efforts and apologize if we're hurrying you along. Just wanted to make sure that this wasn't forgotten.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right, this is now done.

First, the easier tag renames:

- [pokemon-super-md](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-super-md) → [pokemon-super-mystery-dungeon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-super-mystery-dungeon)
- [pokemon-explorers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-explorers) → [pokemon-mystery-dungeon-explorers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-mystery-dungeon-explorers)

Now, for the main series games. While renaming I went through and done a thorough review of all Pokemon Generation tags and their synonyms. Each generation has an overarching Generation tag (For Gen 1 and 2, this is the main tag as only one set of games was released in those generations). All individual game tags have been expanded to use full game names as per this meta discussion.

Here's the final results:

---

### First Generation

- **Generation Tag:** [pokemon-first-generation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-first-generation)
  <sup>Synonyms: [pokemon-red](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-red), [pokemon-blue](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-blue), [pokemon-yellow](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-yellow), [pokemon-green](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-green), [pokemon-rby](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-rby) [pokemon-1st-generation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-1st-generation)</sup>

### Second Generation

- **Generation Tag:** [pokemon-second-generation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-second-generation)
  <sup>Synonyms: [pokemon-gold](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-gold), [pokemon-silver](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-silver), [pokemon-crystal](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-crystal), [pokemon-gsc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-gsc) [pokemon-2nd-generation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-2nd-generation)</sup>

### Third Generation

- **Generation Tag:** [pokemon-third-generation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-third-generation)
  <sup>Synonyms: [pokemon-3rd-generation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-3rd-generation)</sup>
- **Game Tags**

  - [pokemon-ruby-sapphire-emerald](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-ruby-sapphire-emerald)
    <sup>Synonyms: [pokemon-ruby](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-ruby), [pokemon-sapphire](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-sapphire), [pokemon-emerald](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-emerald), [pokemon-rse](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-rse)</sup>
  - [pokemon-fire-red-leaf-green](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-fire-red-leaf-green)
    <sup>Synonyms: [pokemon-fire-red](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-fire-red), [pokemon-leaf-green](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-leaf-green), [pokemon-frlg](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-frlg)</sup>

### Fourth Generation

- **Generation Tag:** [pokemon-fourth-generation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-fourth-generation)
  <sup>Synonyms: [pokemon-4th-generation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-4th-generation)</sup>
- **Game Tags**

  - [pokemon-diamond-pearl-platinum](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-diamond-pearl-platinum)
    <sup>Synonyms: [pokemon-diamond](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-diamond), [pokemon-pearl](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-pearl), [pokemon-platinum](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-platinum), [pokemon-dpp](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-dpp)</sup>
  - [pokemon-heart-gold-soul-silver](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-heart-gold-soul-silver)
    <sup>Synonyms: [pokemon-heart-gold](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-heart-gold), [pokemon-soul-silver](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-soul-silver), [pokemon-hgss](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-hgss)</sup>

### Fifth Generation

- **Generation Tag:** [pokemon-fifth-generation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-fifth-generation)
  <sup>Synonyms: [pokemon-5th-generation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-5th-generation)</sup>
- **Game Tags**

  - [pokemon-black-white](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-black-white)
    <sup>Synonyms: [pokemon-black](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-black), [pokemon-white](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-white), [pokemon-bw](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-bw)</sup>
  - [pokemon-black-2-white-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-black-2-white-2)
    <sup>Synonyms: [pokemon-black-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-black-2), [pokemon-white-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-white-2), [pokemon-bw2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-bw2)</sup>

### Sixth Generation

- **Generation Tag:** [pokemon-sixth-generation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-sixth-generation)
  <sup>Synonyms: [pokemon-6th-generation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-6th-generation)</sup>
- **Game Tags**

  - [pokemon-x-y](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-x-y)
    <sup>Synonyms: [pokemon-x](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-x), [pokemon-y](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-y), [pokemon-xy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-xy)</sup>
  - [pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire)
    <sup>Synonyms: [pokemon-omega-ruby](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-omega-ruby), [pokemon-alpha-sapphire](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-alpha-sapphire), [pokemon-oras](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-oras)</sup>

### Seventh Generation

- **Generation Tag:** [pokemon-seventh-generation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-seventh-generation)
  <sup>Synonyms: [pokemon-7th-generation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-7th-generation)</sup>
- **Game Tags**

  - [pokemon-sun-moon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-sun-moon)
    <sup>Synonyms: [pokemon-sun](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-sun), [pokemon-moon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-moon), [pokemon-sm](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-sm)</sup>
  - [pokemon-ultra-sun-ultra-moon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-ultra-sun-ultra-moon)
    <sup>Synonyms: [pokemon-ultra-sun](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-ultra-sun), [pokemon-ultra-moon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-ultra-moon), [pokemon-usum](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-usum)</sup>

Comment: Well done! You deserve a [Lava Cookie](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Lava_Cookie)!